# Validate that input is in this time format - "HH:MM"

Tags: php, regex, validation, preg-match

I'm trying to use `preg_match` to validate that a time input is in this format - "HH:MM"

Answer (score 89, accepted):

You can use regular expressions to check that.

for 12-hour:

```
preg_match("/^(?:1[012]|0[0-9]):[0-5][0-9]$/", $foo)
```

for 24-hour:

```
preg_match("/^(?:2[0-3]|[01][0-9]):[0-5][0-9]$/", $foo)
```

If you use a 24-hour clock going from **01:00** to **24:59**, use

```
preg_match("/^(?:2[0-4]|[01][1-9]|10):([0-5][0-9])$/", $foo)
```

Comment: +1 for a specific and concise regex.

Comment: can you guys please explain how your answer work? I'd like to not only get an answer from you guys, but also try to learn regex.

Comment: this actually doesn't work for anything 12:xx. doesn't work for 12:00 or 12:30 etc.

Comment: simple fix. Just changed "/(1[01]|... to "/(1[0-2]|

Comment: sorry, but really? reading this without a comment is bah. why not use something as simple as this: `$dateObj = DateTime::createFromFormat('d.m.Y H:i', "10.10.2010 " .$timeStr);
    if ($dateObj !== false) { // valid time} else { //invalid time}`
but yeah, give +14 upvotes for reinventing the wheel

Comment: @Toskan: I think that's a fine way to do it. I tried to follow the OP's request to use `preg_match`, even though I don't know the reasoning behind it. I know that I've asked questions before and had people tell me that I shouldn't do what I was asking to do (rather than tell me how to do it) and it bothered me -- of course I had a reason for asking for what I wanted. I don't know what this poster's reasoning is: maybe they're using GeSHi to format dates in their language and so `DateTime::createFromFormat` isn't available. Or maybe they're just learning regex. I don't know.

Comment: @Charles you are right, fair enough. OP should have taken 15 seconds to actually formulate a question.

Comment: Normally, the 12-hour clock runs from 01:00 to 12:59.  The 12-hour regex allows 00:00 .. 00:59, which are not normally valid times in the 12-hour clock. Also, why are you capturing the hour and not the minutes?  Symmetry suggests neither or both.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: I've never seen that, interesting. I added it as an alternate.

Comment: @Toskan My hosting service is out of date and DateTime object won't work, there.

Comment: according to this 24:59 is a valid hour

Comment: @themis The third regex intentionally allows this. The first two intentionally disallow this.

Comment: You need to match exact result with this : `preg_match("/^(2[0-3]|[01][0-9]):([0-5][0-9])$/", $foo) ` otherwise you could validate this hour : `12:00z`

Comment: It doesn't work for `9:45`, for example. But for `09:45`, it does.

Comment: @Pathros Right -- I'm validating HH:MM, not H:MM.

Comment: worked for me today.+1

Comment: @Pathros To validate both `09:45` and `9:45` use this regexp: `"/^(?(?=\d{2})(?:2[0-3]|[01][0-9])|[0-9]):[0-5][0-9]$/"` See my answer to this question with explanation.

Comment: 24:59 shouldn't be a valid time... Never saw it in my life, PHP silently [converts it to 00:59](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13060823/1677209).

Comment: Hello, this answer should be marked as not right, as the DateTime:createFromFormat method is already providing the right solution which uses the right type: DateTime .

Comment: @Funder Certainly, when you have access to that, I think that's a great solution. My solution is for those, presumably including the OP, who wish to use regular expressions. There are various reasons for wanting this, and it's more important for me to answer the question asked than to answer a different, related question (even though that question is more common). Personally, my view is that that answer is not really a valid answer to this question (though as it has a fair number of votes, it should certainly remain as it has apparently helped people).

Answer (score 26):

Simple function that validates a date (and/or time) without throwing exceptions. It takes the expected [date format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) as a parameter:

```
function isValidDate(string $date, string $format = 'Y-m-d'): bool
{
    $dateObj = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $date);
    return $dateObj && $dateObj->format($format) == $date;
}
```

How it works: it converts the input date into a PHP `DateTime` object according to the passed `$format`, then compares this object with the original input date. 
If they match, the date is valid and has the expected format.

Some usage examples:

```
/* Valid Examples: */
isValidDate("2017-05-31");
isValidDate("23:15:00", 'H:i:s');
isValidDate("2017-05-31 11:15:00", 'Y-m-d h:i:s');

/* Invalid: */
isValidDate("2012-00-21");
isValidDate("25:15:00", 'H:i:s');
isValidDate("Any string that's not a valid date/time");
```

Comment: This is the best one.
I don't see why other people are using regex when there is an official DateTime Class. You know why? Some other people spent their time, and when a class is the official one provided for a language, usually it has been tested so many times, plus, it will for sure be generic, and considering international issues. Expecially when you're dealing with date and times. Those people worked hours, consuming human and electrical energy. Don't waste both, it's the basis for a good developer ;) I know, it's an heavy tought, but it's right

Comment: Certainly, if you don't need regex, this is the way to go.

Comment: This can be used as a simple true/false check.  The return value is false or an instance of the dateTime object, so a simple `if(DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i',$time))` is good for a lot of cases.

Comment: @Snapey the main problem with that approach is that `createFromFormat` accepts "stupid" values like month 13, or day 0. The date `2000-13-00` will be considered valid as it parses it as 2000-12-31.

Answer (score 12):

Let's imagine the time you want to check is `$timeStr` and has to be the format `H:i` according to the date specs.
Using a regex for this is IMHO silly. This is so much easier to read:

**UPDATED**

```
$timeStr = " 02:00"; //example of valid time, note whitespace
test($timeStr);
$timeStr = "23:59"; //valid
test($timeStr);
$timeStr = "24:00"; //invalid
test($timeStr);
$timeStr = "25:00"; //invalid
test($timeStr);    
$timeStr = "16:61"; // invalid
test($timeStr);

//tests 23:59 hour format
    function test($timeStr){

    $dateObj = DateTime::createFromFormat('d.m.Y H:i', "10.10.2010 " . $timeStr);

    if ($dateObj !== false && $dateObj && $dateObj->format('G') == 
        intval($timeStr)){
        //return true;
        echo 'valid  <br/>';
    }
    else{
      //return false;
      echo 'invalid <br/>';
    }

}
```

Comment: Except according to this, 25:00 is a valid hour.

Comment: 1 am of the next day, its a feature

Comment: Create an offSet date and validate against it to remove inputs like 25:00.



 $dateObjOffset = DateTime::createFromFormat('d.m.Y H:i', "10.10.2010 " . '24:00');

        if($dateObjOffset <= $dateObj){
            return false;
        }

Comment: @LakshithaUdara good solution if for the case you want to have 24:00 as valid time, i added a solution for valid until 23:59 that is a bit simpler

Comment: 16:61 is also a valid hour. Also a feature, but perhaps not intended.

Answer (score 8):

Function that validates hours, minutes and seconds, according to the desired format:

```
function validTime($time, $format='H:i:s') {
    $d = DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d $format", "2017-12-01 $time");
    return $d && $d->format($format) == $time;
}
```

---

## How to use:

```
$valid = validTime("23","H");
$valid = validTime("23:59","H:i");
$valid = validTime("23:59:59","H:i:s");
$valid = validTime("23:59:59");
```

#### valid = true

```
$valid = validTime("25","H");
$valid = validTime("01:60","H:i");
$valid = validTime("01:20:61","H:i:s");
$valid = validTime("01:20:61");
```

#### valid = false

Comment: You don't need to hardcode "Y-m-d" and "2017-12-01" there, it just makes it more complicated to understand and less flexible imo

Comment: T30 says the truth, I've just tested. 
Btw, I don't see why other people are using regex when there is an  official DateTime Class.

You know why? Some other people spent their time, and when a class is the official one provided for a language, usually it has been tested so many times, plus, it will for sure be generic, and considering international issues. Expecially when you're dealing with date and times. 

Those people worked hours, consuming human and electrical energy. Don't waste both, it's the basis for a good developer ;) 

I know, it's an heavy tought, but it's right.

Comment: @Funder The basis of good software engineering is using code the software engineer knows works.  Many coders are scared of regex's complexity. It takes real commitment to understand regex. PHP is a great language, but I have run into several PHP bugs. That's what bug reporting is for. "usually it has been tested so many times, plus, it will for sure be generic, and considering international issues." This is the "the guy I don't know is always smarter than I" fallacy. Just about every PHP manual page has error and issue discussions below the description, including the DateTime class.

Comment: @BlueWater I think that I see what you are saying. But date & time for me, is a topic very prone to errors. There are many formats, and rules to know... Regexes are complicated, but if mastered are a very useful tool, I'm not saying that they are not indicated for this purpose. I was referring to the fact that the php DateTime class is more than 10yrs old, and includes already all the RFC/ISO standars. Why bother reimplementing the wheel? Then if a bugs comes out, is there that must be reported, so anyone will benefit from the fix. I think that this topic started in ancient Greece ;-D

Comment: "Why bother reimplementing the wheel?"  To make the wheel better.  Cheers.

Answer (score 4):

here is a code that check if the string is an hour between 00:00 and 23:59

```
$checked = false;
    if (preg_match('/^\d{2}:\d{2}$/', $str)) {
        if (preg_match("/(2[0-3]|[0][0-9]|1[0-9]):([0-5][0-9])/", $str)) {
            $checked = true;
        }
    }
    var_dump($checked );die;
```

Comment: This is matching `24:15` but not `10:15`

Comment: @Toto - Fixed check now

Comment: This is what I was looking for...thanks ..

Answer (score 3):

You can do:

```
if(preg_match('/^(?:[01][0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]$/',$input)) {
        // $input is valid HH:MM format.
}
```

Comment: This would allow 24:59. That's not a valid time. Furthermore, why aren't you capturing the hour and minute?

Comment: console.log('24:59'.match(/^(?:[01][0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]$/)) 
will output null , this pattern not allow 24:59

Answer (score 2):

For a 12-hour match that can do am and pm, use this

```
/^(1[0-2]|0?[1-9]):[0-5][0-9] (AM|PM)$/i
```

It will handle 01:20 am  or 1:20 AM.
The examples above for 12 hour were incorrect because you could potentially do:

```
00:20
```

which is not a valid 12 hour format.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on what @Toskan wrote, you could do this to validate in 00:00 format. Returns true if valid and between 00:00 and 23:59.

This also allows different time formats to be used...

```
function isTimeValid($time_str, $format = 'H:i')
{
    $DateTime = \DateTime::createFromFormat( "d/m/Y {$format}", "10/10/2010 {$time_str}" );
    return $DateTime && $DateTime->format( "d/m/Y {$format}" ) == "10/10/2010 {$time_str}";
}
```

Comment: please check the answer by TILiBRA

Comment: @Funder Same answer with seconds added. However, the question was for evaluating HH:MM, not anything else. Of course the hard-coding is not necessary if one wanted to add flexibility or turn it into a isDateTimeValid() function...

Comment: Yes mate, but you can just create a function like validateDateTime(string $dateTime, string $format = "H:i") { ..... } this way you have a base function that checks by default the HH:MM format, while you can pass another valid format you want. Like a date, a date + time, time with seconds... It's important to focus on the right method to validate a date/time, by not using a regex, if there's a official method to do it. In future that method will be updated with new features, while a regex remains like that forever.

Comment: That is correct, and I am aware and that is what I was trying to convey if I wasn't clear. I also agree that it is not necessary to use regex, which is why I didn't in the example...

Comment: You're right, I was referring to other answers, in particular the one that was accepted as the solution. I don't know why the method like the one you used was not choosen as the right solution. Maybe when the question was posted, the DateTime class hadn't the createFromFormat method. I will take a look.
**EDIT:** DateTime::createFromFormat was introduced in v5.3.0, released in 2009, so one year before the original question. :'(

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't requiring `preg_match`, here is another novel method:

```
$thetime = "20:15" // set the time
$timecheck = explode(":", filter_var($thetime, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
$hourvalid = $minvalid = false;
if (count($timecheck) > 1 && count($timecheck) < 4) {
   $hourvalid = ((abs(filter_var($timecheck[0], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT)) < 24) 
                && (abs(filter_var($timecheck[0], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT)) === (INT) $timecheck[0]))
                ? true : false;
      $minvalid = ((abs(filter_var($timecheck[1], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT)) < 60) 
                && (abs(filter_var($timecheck[1], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT)) === (INT) $timecheck[1])) 
                ? true : false;
}

if ($hourvalid && $minvalid) {//valid time         
   echo $thetime . " is a valid time<br />";
} else {//invalid time
   echo $thetime . " is NOT a valid time<br />";
}
```

Probably not the most efficient method in the world, but it gets it done.  Valid only for times from `00:00` to `23:59`.  Also, `8:0` validates as a time (assuming you would mean `08:00`).

Comment: I wouldn't be sure about not-the-most-efficient, this is just comparing and type checking, this actually could be the most efficient way :) (though this is just microoptimalization, which is mostly not worth the effort) :) **Also**, I think `FILTER_SANITIZE_URL` is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

Corrected answer for @Toskan if you only want to validate HH:MM string

```
     protected function isValidTime($timeStr){

    $dateObj = DateTime::createFromFormat('d.m.Y H:i', "10.10.2010 " . $timeStr);
    $dateObjOffset = DateTime::createFromFormat('d.m.Y H:i', "10.10.2010 " . '24:00');

    if($dateObjOffset <= $dateObj){
        return false;
    }
    if ($dateObj !== false) {
       return true;
    }
    else{
       return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the Charles's elegant answer with regular expression. If you need a one line validation of both `"HH:MM"` and `"H:MM"` (i.e. `"9:45"`/`"09:45"`) use the following regexp to match 24-hour format:

```
preg_match("/^(?(?=\d{2})(?:2[0-3]|[01][0-9])|[0-9]):[0-5][0-9]$/", $time)
```

### Explanation

`(?` stands for [conditional subpattern](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.conditional.php), the syntax is:

> (?(**condition**)**yes-pattern**|**no-pattern**)

`?=` in **condition** is the [regexp assertion](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.assertions.php)

`?:` in **yes-pattern** is *optional* for better performance and you may drop it. This means we don't need any [capturing](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.subpatterns.php) within parentheses `()`, we need just alternatives feature.

So, we merely describe the following:

1. If `$time` string begins with two digits `(?=\d{2})`, use `(2[0-3]|[01][0-9])` pattern to match HH-hour notation (`"09:45"` case)
2. otherwise use `[0-9]` pattern to match H-hour notation (`"9:45"` case)

## UPDATE

As they say, simplicity is the sister of a talent. We don't necessarily need the condition pattern described above. The simpler validation of `"HH:MM/H:MM"` for **24-hour** format:

```
preg_match("/^(?:2[0-3]|[01][0-9]|[0-9]):[0-5][0-9]$/", $time)
```

Again, `?:` in grouping parentheses `()` is optional to disable capturing, you can drop it.

So, in this regexp the alternative subpatterns withing `()` is trying to match two digits hour at the first (`20..23`) and second (`01..19`) pattern, then one digit at the last third one (`0..9`).

In addition, the validation of `"HH:MM/H:MM"` for **12-hour** format:

```
preg_match("/^(?:0?[1-9]|1[012]):[0-5][0-9]$/", $time);
```

Here, we're trying to match at first one digit (`1..9`) with possible preceding zero (`0?`), and then two digits (`10..12`).

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for seconds (24hour). This worked like a charm for me.

```
$time = "23:59:60";    
preg_match("/^([0-1][0-9]|2[0-3]):([0-5][0-9]):([0-5][0-9])$/", $time)
```

Comment: 23:59:60 shouldn't be a valid time... :\

Answer (score -5):

Another approch without using regex.

```
if(is_string($foo)  && (strlen($foo) == 4 || strlen($foo) == 5) && intval(str_replace(':','',$foo)) > -1 && intval(str_replace(':','',$foo)) < 2360){
    stuff to do if valid time
}
else{
    stuff to do if invalid time
}
```

First of all I check if the datatype is string. If not it obvious that it is not a valid time. Then I check if the string has the right lenght of 4 / 5 letters.
With str_replace I remove the ':' and then cast the result to an integer which I could easily compare to the desired time range (in my example 00:00 - 23:59).