# Regular expression for timestamp

Tags: php, regex, validation

I am working on validation for timestamp. Here is my code.

It is not supposed to accept string like "16:59'99" or "16:59'999" as the 2 digits after ' should be less than 59 but it actually accepted those invalid format. What's wrong with my regex?

```
function isValidTimeStampFormat($timestamp){

$pattern = "(^(2[0-3]|[0-1]{0,1}[0-9]):[0-5][0-9]'[0-5][0-9].[0-9]{1,3}$)|
            (^(2[0-3]|[0-1]{0,1}[0-9]):[0-5][0-9]'[0-5][0-9]$)|
            (^(2[0-3]|[0-1]{0,1}[0-9]):[0-5][0-9].[0-9]{1,3}$)|
            (^(2[0-3]|[0-1]{0,1}[0-9]):[0-5][0-9]$)";

return (preg_match("<$pattern>", $timestamp) == 1)? true : false;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [validate this format - "HH:MM"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3964972/validate-this-format-hhmm)

Comment: What about [this](https://regexr.com/3jlpt)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.` in the first and third lines means match anything, not match a dot, so use `\.` instead to match a literal dot.

```
$pattern = "(^(2[0-3]|[0-1]{0,1}[0-9]):[0-5][0-9]'[0-5][0-9]\.[0-9]{1,3}$)|
            (^(2[0-3]|[0-1]{0,1}[0-9]):[0-5][0-9]'[0-5][0-9]$)|
            (^(2[0-3]|[0-1]{0,1}[0-9]):[0-5][0-9]\.[0-9]{1,3}$)|
            (^(2[0-3]|[0-1]{0,1}[0-9]):[0-5][0-9]$)";
```

With just a dot there, the `'` was being matched.

See the [online demo here](https://www.regextester.com/?fam=100090).

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try this:

```
^([0-9]|0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]'[0-5][0-9][0-9]$
```

Check this on [Regxr](https://regexr.com/3jlpt)