# How to ensure if user input is in this format "H:MM AM/PM, DURATION MIN/HR?

Tags: php, html

I have a user input which requires the user to enter the time in this format.

```
<input type="text" name="time" placeholder="Type in this format: H:MM AM/PM, DURATION MIN/HR">
```

After form submit, I need a PHP script to check if the user follow this format **H:MM AM/PM, DURATION MINS/HRS**. Below are example of the data format that the user must follow when enter:

```
E.g.
8:00 AM, 1 HR
3:00 PM, 20 MIN
11:00 AM, 15 MIN
```

How do I ensure user follow this format using PHP?

Comment: Have you tried writing anything?

Comment: You can't guarantee that a user follows that format. In fact, in a free text field you'll be lucky if your users follow exactly that format at all. If you break it down into separate fields for time, AM/PM, etc you'll have more luck, but that's a job for HTML

Answer (score 0):

This would be difficult to validate fully. Perhaps a regular expression could be made to do it, but it's going to be complex. Also I don't think this is user-friendly for the people trying to type it.

From a user experience point of view it would be a lot better to have to input boxes - one for time, one for duration, and just let the user type the numbers. It's far easier to validate, and the AM/PM is superfluous if you use 24hr times, as is the MIN.

Something like this would make your users a lot happier:

```html
Time: <input type="time" name="time"/>
Duration: <input type="number" name="duration"/> MIN
```

P.S. You didn't say why you require this specific, esoteric format but presumably if you really do require it for some display later, you can easily re-create it from the input given by the user.

You can also validate the values entered by the user more easily in PHP (when they arrive at your server) to check they are valid times and numbers. You can use one of the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3964972/validate-that-input-is-in-this-time-format-hhmm) to validate the time string. You can use the [ctype_digit](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-digit.php) function to check that the duration is a valid integer.

I assume you aren't intending to store it like that in your database or anything because it would be very inefficient in terms of being able to filter, sort or otherwise query it.